# Who saves the last ssh login infos under Linux?

Tags: linux, ssh

I had this question (or better, these questions) bugging me lately, so I hope someone here would be so kind to answer me.
Basically, when you ssh into a remote Linux server, you receive a greeting message like this:

> Last Login: Thu Aug 7 09:45:32 from whatever.your.ip.address.was.com

So I'm wondering:
1) Who's in charge, under Linux, to detect the IP address of the user that just logged in?
1) who's in charge to save that info, and where is stored?

My first guess was ssh, but now i think there could be a library for that, and ssh simply uses that lib.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well ssh is the command you launch *in your computer* to estabilish a connection to a remote server. I'm not a guru on this topic, but you might want to have a look into **sshd** (the "d" at the end is not a typo), which is the daemon that manages ssh connections.

Comment: Thanks for your time sir, but i need a more explicit answer